# Using \w not working as expected in reg-ex matching when I use egrep

Tags: grep

I want to only return lines that have at least one alphabet or number.

Using `egrep "[a-zA-Z0-9]"` works
but not `egrep "[\w]"`

Example below.

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

```
echo '*****Full Input*****';cat GrepTestLog.log; echo '*****After RegEx match*****';cat GrepTestLog.log | egrep "[a-zA-Z0-9]"
*****Full Input*****
AB123C-1 *nbqtwrt 
AAABA1524 
BAAAAA1524
AA A
AAAA
&&*&* +_+_
*****After RegEx match*****
AB123C-1 *nbqtwrt 
AAABA1524 
BAAAAA1524
AA A
TYABQEHD$
AAAA
```

But \w does work

```
echo '*****Full Input*****';cat GrepTestLog.log; echo '*****After RegEx match*****';cat GrepTestLog.log | egrep "[\w]"
*****Full Input*****
AB123C-1 *nbqtwrt 
AAABA1524 
BAAAAA1524
AA A
AAAA
&&*&* +_+_
*****After RegEx match*****
AB123C-1 *nbqtwrt
```

Comment: Do you mean "Using egrep "[\w]" works but not egrep "[a-zA-Z0-9]" ? Also, could you provide some examples of what your expected output would be?

Comment: Yes.  The examples are in the question. See the two embedded snippets shown as code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, none of the BRE/ERE implementations support use of character sets like `\s`, `\w`, etc inside bracket expressions. If you have `GNU grep`, then you can use `grep -P` which does allow them inside bracket expressions.

As an alternate, you can use `[[:alnum:]]` to match only alphabets or numbers. `[_[:alnum:]]` would be similar to `\w`

See https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions for full list.

Comment: In POSIX terminology `[:alnum:]` is a character class while `[[:alnum:]]` is a character class within a bracket expression. Given that, it doesn't make sense to talk about `\s` or any other escape sequence inside a character class because if they appeared as `[\s]` they're not inside a character class, they're inside a bracket expression. I know there's other terminology out there that muddies the term "character class" but it's best to stick to POSIX terminology as it's clear, simple, and consistent.